# Unable to send automated mail using udev and msmtp

Tags: bash, udev, usb-device, msmtp

I am trying to write a script to send an  email whenever a usb device is connected to my computer (Arch Linux). The code I wrote is

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
    echo "USB inserted at $(date) for $1 and $2" >> /home/user/commands/logs.log
    cd ~
    ip -4 addr | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}' > /home/user/commands/testing.txt
    echo -e "Subject: Hello \n\nBody:usb inserted at $(ip -4 addr | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}')\nthrough the mail" | msmtp mymail@gmail.com
fi
```

the script is supposed to send the ipv4 address to the mail. The usb insertion is being detected and the log file and testing txt file is being written.

But the mail is not being sent. I wrote the mail code separately through the terminal and it seems to be working. But inside the code, the mail is not getting run.

I have set the msmtp working. I have checked using terminal commands directly and it is working. But through the script it is not working.

All other commands are getting executed and I am getting the files.

This is my rules script

```
ACTION=="add",\
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",\
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",\
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usbinserted.sh '%E{DEVTYPE}' '%E{DEVNAME}'"
```

Comment: Using the script through `udev` may be using root user, and the default `.msmtprc` is usually in your user directory.  You might need to set "default" `msmtp` user to root.

Comment: @J.Cravens Yeah I set the .msmtprc in root home directory aswell. Thats the reason for `ch ~`  when it changes to root home directory.

Comment: pwd is `/root` and who is`root`. I added .msmtprc file in `/root`

Comment: Any luck?  Do you have the entries configured?  I made a [helper script](https://github.com/jaycrav3ns/misc_scripts/blob/main/shellscripts/email_from_console.sh) to setup `msmtp` a couple of months ago.

Comment: None so far. I ran the file you shared. Made some changes to accomodate pacman. Set up the .msmtprc file. But still issue persists. I can send the mail directly through the command line. But the same command inside the udev rule shell script it is not working. I think it is not the msmtp issue but some issue with the udev command script

Comment: *"But the same command inside the udev rule shell script it is not working."* . This often indicates a $PATH problem. Try (as a test) rewriting to use `/full/path/to/msmtp` . Good luck.